# How to trace the location of incoming call in android

Tags: android

I want to trace the location of  incoming call in android programming. I don't have any idea whether there is any api in android or not.. If any one have some knowledge, please share with me...

Comment: Analyse the phone number... +1 is USA, +49 is Germany and so on... +4930xxx would be somebody from Berlin Germany.

Answer (score 0):

Try to parse the phonenumber.
Every country begins with a country code and so on...